# How to show 2 tables value in gridview using where clause on date column

Tags: c#, asp.net, select, gridview, where-clause

i tried to show 2 tables value in one gridview in asp.net using where clause on date

```
    string s = "select Stock.Date,Stock.OpeningStock,Stock.Purchase,Stock.Total,Stock.Sell,Stock.ClosingStock, Sell.qty,Sell.Rate,Sell.Amount from Stock LEFT JOIN Sell ON Stock.Date = Sell.Date";
```

But it shows same Date data 2 times, i want only 1 time

it shows like this

02-10-2018 00:00:00 |894       | 1000    1894   561 1333    561 90  50490

02-10-2018 00:00:00 894     1000    1894    561 1333    561 80  44880

02-10-2018 00:00:00 1333    8000    9333    561 8772    561 90  50490

02-10-2018 00:00:00 1333    8000    9333    561 8772    561 80  44880

[image]

Comment: You probably have duplicate rows in table `Stock` and/or `Sell`.

Comment: no...there is no duplicate rows in the table

Answer (score -1):

You can try use SELECT DISTINCT.

Comment: no he can't just throw a distinct, its a join issue on the query